# Rails 4.2 get ActiveRecords Range Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an ID(Int) in database with limit `11`.

I am using Rails 4.2 and if I type number larger than 11 digits I get Rails `RangeError` as ex:

`123456789955 is out of range for ActiveRecord::Type::Integer with limit 4`

It is ok but I want instead of the error to get some alert like:

`Please do not type long numbers`

Sample Code:

```
case params[:search_for]
  when 'order'
    @orders = Order.recent
                .where(orders_id: params[:search])
                .paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 100)
```

and `scope :recent, -> { order(orders_id: :desc) }`

Comment: Why not use `rescue` on `RangeError` and present whatever message you want?

Comment: @tadman how can I do that pls ?